# Differential sync (add, delete but no overwrite) of one ArrayList from another Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

new data:

```
ArrayList<Comment> newComments =  getComments();
```

already existing data, has some data already filled in:

```
ArrayList<Comment> oldComments
```

I can't overwrite entire old contents with new ones.

I want new (not already present) `Comment` objects in `newComments` to be added to `oldComments`, also I want those missing in `newComments` to be removed from `oldComments`.

Is there some good method in `Collections` package for this ? or any other way ?

NOTE: `Comment` class has custom `compare()` method (not using default `equals()` )

Comment: After the operation `oldComments` will be same as `newComments`?

Comment: Only in the case when `newComments` have no such item that is similar ( `compare()` method is true ) to ones in `oldComments`.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I meant that their contents will be same, i.e. `compare()` will return `true` for the two. You have found a satisfactory answer but can you clarify you can't "can't overwrite entire old contents with new ones." ?

Comment: @MiserableVariable Yes `Compare()` will return true. `Compare()` just compares title and author property of the `Comment` object not whole contents. for example, these comments we are writing on Stackoverflow, lets say you are editing one of your comments, also want the comments section to refresh automatically. On refresh new comments added by users will show, also comments which other users deleted should not be here any more , and whatever you were editing should not be overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `java.util.Set` is more appropriate for your use case. Then you can do:

```
oldComments.retainAll(newComments);
oldComments.addAll(newComments);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll need to implement custom `equals()` and `hashcode()` though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`CollectionUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) from the Apache foundation and the `union()` method.

Beware that you need to make sure that the `Comment` class overrides the `equals()` method to make sure to have the effective union and not the concatenation of the two lists.

Comment: `union` will retain entries in the old that are not in the new, OP wants them removed.